# C++, do functions know previously computed function values or do they have to recompute them?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a very costly function that checks if an object has a certain property. Another function would then, depending on whether the object has the property, do different things.

If I have previously checked for the property, would it be recomputed by the second function, or is it known?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
bool check_property(object){
    // very costly operations...
}

void do_something(object){
    if(check_property) {do thing}
    else {do different thing}
}
```

Would the `if` in `do_something` recompute `check_property`?

Comment: You could use a static variable in the function

Comment: Yes. C++ does what you tell it to, for the most part. If you tell it to call check_property, it's going to. What you're asking about is called memoization, and there are a variety of ways to implement it. But you have to opt into it.

Comment: There are compiler-specific extensions which might allow the optimizer to rearrange your code to reduce calls to the function, but the compiler can’t do that in general (for all it knows, `check_property` modifies some global state and you’re calling it for that instead of for the result). Even if you do tell the compiler a function is pure, it’s not guaranteed to optimize away multiple calls. You need to handle your own memoization if you want that.

Comment: The if would compute check_property once if you need to see the value times in the function store the output in a bool variable

Comment: Compute it.  Assign it to something.  Re-use it.  If the computation is simple enough, the compiler may do this for you (if it doesn't touch any externals or globals, so it can be sure that the call is deterministic.)

Comment: What if the object changed? How does the compiler know whether it's safe to remember the result?

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted?  It seems like a fine and interesting question to me.

Comment: @DonHatch perhaps it is seen as too trivial and not very thought out. I don't know, I always get downvoted here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several factors that have to come together for the compiler to avoid recomputing the function's result:

1. The compiler has to know which input values the function's result depends on. This knowledge is very difficult to extract from the code in general case. In some implementations you can help the compiler by using compiler-specific means to declare your function as "pure" or "const" ([GCC function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes))
2. The compiler has to make sure that the above input values did not change since the previous call to the same function. This might be very easy in some specific case, but is also very difficult in general case.
3. The compiler has to have the result of previous computation readily available. Normally, compilers do not deliberately "cache" such results in some dedicated storage for future reuse. The optimization in question is typically applied only when you make multiple calls to the same function in "close proximity" to each other, meaning that the previous result is easy to keep till the moment of the next call.

So, the optimization in question is certainly possible. But it is something you should expect to see in simple and very localized cases, like calling `sqrt(x)` several times in a row for the same value of `x` (in the same expression, in the same cycle and such). But for more complicated functions it is typically going to be your responsibility to either somehow avoid making multiple calls to the same expensive function, or maybe *memoize* the results if you believe it can benefit your code.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the compiler can prove that `check_property` has no side effects and that all the data it depends from is the same, it is not allowed to remove the call; for all practical purposes, unless your function body is known in the current TU, it is pretty much trivial and the multiple calls happen in the same function, calling again will execute its code again. I don't know of any compiler that establish automatically a cross-call cache, because it's not trivial at all.

If you need to cache the computed values, in general you will have to do it yourself; keep in mind that it's not always trivial - generally the ugly beasts to tackle are cache invalidation (how do I know that the data used to calculate the value didn't change from the last time I calculated it? how do I avoid the cache size getting out of hand?) and multithreading concerns (is this code going to be called from multiple threads? if so, I have to synchronize the access to the cache, possibly adding coupling between unrelated threads and, in extreme cases, killing the efficiency of the cache itself).

Comment: First paragraph: essentially right, and you've done a good job of enumerating the circumstances under which it can happen; however, it looks to me like you've thrown in some strange subjective bits, making it sound pretty grim.  Note that (1) the way the question is posed, the function body *is* known in the current TU, (2) the "multiple calls happen in the same function" condition includes the case of indirect calls through other functions in the same TU (3) once all the other conditions are met, common subexpression elimination may well eliminate calls, even of surprising complexity.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes. It will rerun it. If you want to make sure that the code doesn't run it again every time you call `do_something`, try adding a variable in your class that will tell you if you already ran it:

```
bool check_property(object){
// very costly operations...
return true;
}

void do_something(object,bool has_run){
if(has_run) {do thing}
else {do different thing}
}

void main() {
bool has_run = false;
has_run = check_property(object);
do_something(object,has_run);
}
```

There are of course multiple ways of doing this, and this might not fit your criteria, but it is a possible way of doing it!

I just realized that this isn't really how C++ works since everything is not in classes unlike Java. Instead you can just pass the value as an argument to the function itself. So, I have edited my code.